# Creating Select All control for IBM BPM table

Tags: javascript, ibm-bpm

I am trying to create a select all in a table in IBM BPM (8.5.5) coach.By default select all button is not provided. Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Thanks much
Anupam

Answer (score 0):

You may change stock table control which uses dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid and add IndirectSelection plugin:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/IndirectSelection.html#dojox-grid-enhancedgrid-plugins-indirectselection